# How to position an element in relation to other elements in a svg

Tags: svg

I have created an SVG chart with many elements. All elements are positioned in percentage. The reason is that the chart must be scalable. It works fine but some elements like the labels of the axis need positioning in relation to other elements.

In this example I have two vertical lines, the first is at 50% and the second at 60%. I want archive that the second line has always a distance of 10 pixel to the first line. And that for every size of the SVG. That mean when the size of the svg change, the first line stay at 50% and the second line is 10px to the right.

```
<svg height="100" width="100">
  <line x1="50%" y1="0" x2="50%" y2="100" style="stroke:rgb(255,0,0);stroke-width:2" />
  <line x1="60%" y1="0" x2="60%" y2="100" style="stroke:rgb(255,0,0);stroke-width:2" />
</svg>
```

I find no way to do this. Hope someone can help me.

Comment: You don't need to position elements in percentages in order to make a **S**calable **V**ector **G**rafic scalable. It is scalable by definition. However it would help giving your SVG a `viewBox` instead of width and height. Try `viewBox="0 0 100 100`

Comment: Yes true but didn't solve my problem. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A general solution to combining relative and absolute units is to nest `<svg>` elements. For your example, this could be:

```css
body { height: 90vh; }
```

```html
<svg height="100%" width="100%">
  <svg x="50%" width="10" height="100%" overflow="visible">
    <line x1="0" y1="0" x2="0" y2="100%" style="stroke:rgb(255,0,0);stroke-width:2" />
    <line x1="10" y1="0" x2="10" y2="100%" style="stroke:rgb(255,0,0);stroke-width:2" />
  </svg>
</svg>
```

Comment: Good solution thanks for that. Feels pretty complicated but I'm afraid there is nothing better.

Answer (score 1):

A cheap solution to your problem would be using 2 lines one over another, together with `vector-effect: non-scaling-stroke;` The first line is wider, and the second line is white as the svg background giving the illusion of 2 lines at a distance of a distance of 10 pixel one from each-other.

```css
svg {
  border: 1px solid;
}
line {
  stroke: rgb(255, 0, 0);
  stroke-width: 14;
  vector-effect: non-scaling-stroke;
}
.center {
  stroke-width: 10;
  stroke: white;
}
```

```html
<svg id="svg" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
  <line x1="50" x2="50" y2="100" />
  <line class="center" x1="50" x2="50" y2="100" />
</svg>
```

Comment: Works for my example but the real problem is a label on the y-axis of a chart. But i like the idea :)

Answer (score -2):

Haven't tried but can't you just add margin-left:10px in style attribute? and let x value 50% in both.